# What is the density of states $SiO_2$?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, density-of-states

We build the model by the finite element method. In our model here is silicon dioxide (SiO2). To carry out calculations, it is necessary to know the density of states and the effective mass.

**Question:**

What is the density of states and effective mass of silicon dioxide (SiO2)? The temperature is 20 °C.

Comment: The density of states, and also the effective mass depend strongly on energy. Please specify in which energy range you are interested.

Comment: @flaudemus Sorry, I do not understand to my own shame what kind of energy we are talking about.

Comment: @flaudemus If it's Bolzman energy, it's kT = 4,0E-21 joule.

Comment: You should specify which phase you are interested (crystalline? amorphous? other?) and I assume, but you should confirm that you are speaking about electronic density of states. It would also help a lot to know which kind of calculations are you planning to do with such a density of states.

Comment: @GiorgioP my calculations in the field of solid-state electronics. SiO2 - it's part of charge-coupled device (photo sensor). Is it enough for understanding?

Comment: I’m having a really hard time seeing how the electronic states of SiO2 figure in to CCD operation. If you are conducting charge through the oxide that would be quite unusual.